# Atom Jscs linter for embedded JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, atom-editor, jscs

I am trying Atom as new editor for my Polymer project, currently I use Sublime Text 3.
Two of the most usefull features I frequently use are Jscs and Jshint so I succesfully installed AtomLinter linter-jshint and linter-jscs https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jscs ( Linter as well since it's a prerequisite ).

While Jshint works like a charm with HTML files containing Polymer components, Jscs linter doesnt.

As reported by AtomLinter in the Readme of his github project the plugin lints only source files with *.js and *.jsx extensions. 
I checked this by Atom developer console.

I spent some time on the web to understand if the limit is related to the core node.js linter node-jscs or is an Atom plugin lack.
Since node-jscs has added this feature  https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/pull/1038 and Sublime Text 3 Jscs plugin based on node-jscs works I am pretty sure AtomLinter hasn't yet developed the feature.
Am I missing something?
Does anybody know how can I have jscs working in Atom for html file with embedded JavaScript in  tag ?

I'd appreciate any kind of reply!
Simone.